# Not able to login via specified user in localhost SQL Server connection string

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I am new to SQL Server and I am trying to connect a localhost SQL Server. And I am having the following exception:

> Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. 
> The Login failed Login failed for user "MyCodingPC\Cyborg".

And also I don't understand why it is getting logged in via that username when I have specified another user in the connection string.

My connection string

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,1433\(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=MyNewUser;Password=pass@#$word;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: `Integrated Security=True` means that it will try to login as your current windows user login.  You should not specify both Integrated Security and a Username/Password, just one or the other.  If you do specify both, Integrated Security will override in most cases.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag correctly and with care. MySQL tag removed

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung I didn't knew about the integreated security thing. But after I have removed it, I am getting another error saying ```Login  failed for user 'MyNewUser'```. Now why is that??

Comment: Any number of reasons: No such username, bad password, the username is not authorized to access the named database, mixed mode logins are not enabled, etc.  There is a secondary code/error that is recorded in the SQL Server logs (if enabled) that can be used to determine what the cause.

Comment: Here is an old article that explains how to determine the cause using the secondary error code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: You're specifying an IP address and port in your connection string. Are you trying to connect to a LocalDB instance on another computer? You'll need at least SQL Server Express edition for that.

Comment: Yes it is the case @AlwaysLearning

Comment: I looked into the Server Log as you said @RBarryYoung and this is what I got

```Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.```

```Login failed for user 'MyNewUser'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]```

Comment: That's the problem then.  SQL Server has two security modes, Integrated authentication-only, which only allows Windows logins and Mixed mode which allows both Windows and SQL Server logins.  You are in Integrated authentication-only and so you cannot use a SQL Login (`...;User Id=MyNewUser;Password=pass@#$word;...`).  Here is an article that explains how you (or your DBA) can change it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: I have already read that document, and I have also set my Server Authentication mode to Mixed mode and also restarted the server a couple of times. Enabled TCP/IP in the sql server configuration manager and allowed 1433 port in the firewall. But still got the same result. Is there anything else I need to do?? @RBarryYoung

Comment: I just used T-SQL script to verify the authentication mode using `SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
          WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication Only'   
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'  
       END as [Authentication Mode];`
And the result was: `Authentication Mode                  
-------
Windows and SQL Server Authentication` @RBarryYoung

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? You may need to restart the SQL Server instance.

Comment: 2018 @RBarryYoung

Comment: Could you figure out what's going wrong in this case?? @RBarryYoung Because I restarted each and every instance and still having the same issue

Comment: If the errorlogs still say that `Server is configured for Integrated authentication only.` after you configured it for mixed mode and restarted, then I have to assume that it is some bug in SQL Server itself.  IIRC, the errorlogs should also indicate what authentication mode the instance is in when you restart the instance.  If that message contradicts the login failure error message in the same log, then I'd suggest taking it to Microsoft.  Alternatively, you could try https://dba.stackexchange,com or https://sqlservercentral.com where they have more specialized expertise.

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung. I have asked about it in [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalDB cannot be used over TCP. So to accomplish my requirements I used SQLExpress instead.

[LocalDB is supposed to work only for local access; remote access is not possible here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9685151c-7930-4f03-9455-842607b47163/how-to-enable-localdb-connection-via-tcpip-in-code-vbnet?forum=sqlexpress)